# Is there an inverse of `vars(object)`

Tags: python

The built-in `vars(obj)` returns a dict with key/values mirroring the attributes of `obj`. Is there an inverse of this function?  I.e. a function that takes a dictionary and returns an object.

I've come up with two ways of doing it, neither of which would be obvious to someone reading it. The first version involves assigning a new dict to `self.__dict__`:

```
class _Tmp(object):
    def __init__(self, dct):
        self.__dict__ = dct
obj = _Tmp({'hello': 'world'})
assert obj.hello == 'world'
```

and the second version uses a non-standard call to the `type` builtin:

```
obj = type('', (), {'hello': 'world'})
assert obj.hello == 'world'
```

Is there an easier/more readable way?

Comment: What makes you think the call to `type()` is *non-standard*?

Comment: @MartijnPieters it has no name and no bases (which all the examples I've seen uses).

Comment: What object would you expect?

Comment: @thebjorn: that's because you gave it an empty string, and you could easily use `(object,)` as the bases. I'm not sure why not using either is non-standard however.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Python 3.3 and up you can use [`types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace):

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

obj = SimpleNamespace(**{'hello': 'world'})
```

Comment: Very interesting thing for Python to provide. Definitely has it's uses, I'm sure, though it reminds me a lot of Javascript objects. And for people who have yet to jump to Python 3, the code given in the documentation worked to define `SimpleNamespace` in my Python 2.7.5.

Comment: It's not clear with OP wants, but this isn't really an exact inverse as vars() as vars() doesn't create a new object and changes to the vars() output are reflected in the original object and vice versa. SimpleNamespace creates a copy which can be modified without changing the original dictionary.

Comment: @KevinShea: it is quite clear what the OP wants, which is to create an object with attributes, taken from a dictionary. `SimpleNamespace` does *exactly* that.

Comment: @KevinShea: I don't think that the OP ever realised that `vars()` just returns a reference to the `__dict__` dictionary of an instance, for example. Nowhere are they asking for such a direct connection. You can't have that kind of connection easily, as the `__dict__` slot of instances is read-only. You can't create instances that take a pre-existing dictionary for their `__dict__` attribute, so you can only do it with explicit `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` and `__delattr__` hooks that translate to a separate attribute that's not named `__dict__`.

Answer (score 4):

There is the module [`attrdict`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/attrdict/1.2.0) that does what you want.